# How to Increment numbers in an array to populate UIPickerView

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, uipickerview, increment

I have a UIPickerView that I am populating with an array.  It has two columns and i need the first column to go from 50-500. the second column to go from 0.01 to 1.  The point is for the user to pick their weight.  For doing the 50-500 I have this,

```
-(void)populateWeightPickerArray{
weightPickerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int weight = 50; weight <=500; weight++) {
    NSString *weightString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%",weight];
    [weightPickerArray addObject:weightString];
}
}
```

I tried doing that with the decimal, however when i use ++ it goes up by whole number and I end up getting 1.01, 2.01, 3.01 etc.  here is what I have for code.

```
-(void)populateWeightPickerArray2{
weightPickerArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (float weightDecimal = .01; weightDecimal <= 10; weightDecimal++) {
    NSString *weightDecimalString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%0.2f",weightDecimal];
    [weightPickerArray2 addObject:weightDecimalString];
}   
}
```

(I know i said I only needed it to go to 1 not 10, but i put 10 because at first it was only displaying 1.01, so i put 10 to test the output until I can get it right.)

So i need to somehow increment it to make it go from .01 to 1 (0.02, 0.03,0.04 etc).  Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (float weightDecimal = .01; weightDecimal <= 10; weightDecimal = weightDecimal + 0.01)
```

or more succinctly:

```
for (float weightDecimal = .01; weightDecimal <= 10; weightDecimal += 0.01)
```

In Objective C: `x += y` is a shorthand for `x = x + y`.

Although you often see `for` loops with `something++` or `something--` you can use any expression.

Comment: What do I use for the string format.. "NSString string with format:???".... I have tried @"%0.01f" and that results in only one decimal being shown (0.1).  I have tried several other things but cannot get the correct format(0.01, 0.02, 0.03,...0.11, 0.12, etc.) @idz

Comment: Your original `@"%0.2f"` should have been OK. (The 0 before the decimal point means you want to show a zero before the decimal point when appropriate and the 2 after means to show two decimal places.)